# trying to record two channels from multi channel audio device into a wav file using the gstreamer c api without gst_parse_launch

Tags: c, gstreamer, wav

I'm trying to record two channels from my Clarret 8pre sound card as stereo to a wav file using the gstreamer api without using `gst_launch` on MacOS using cpp, but i use the c api of gstreamer.

i was able to perform that from the terminal using:

`gst-launch-1.0 osxaudiosrc device=97 ! audioconvert ! deinterleave name=d interleave name=i ! audioconvert ! wavenc ! filesink location=stereo.wav d.src_4 ! queue ! i.sink_0 d.src_5 ! queue ! i.sink_1`

but as i learned the gstreamer api is a bit different.

so in general i first connect and link `osxaudiosource device=97 ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! capsfilter ! deinterleave` and separately i connect `interleave ! encoder ! sink`

then in the `pad-added` callback to the `deinterleave` element, i pass the `interleave` element as a data, i wait for `src_4` and `src_5` from `deinterleave` and connect them to new sinks `sink_0` and `sink_1` created by  `gst_element_request_pad_simple(sink, "sink_%u");`

the `capsfilter` is probably not needed, i was trying to see how to overcome the warning the i get which causes the pipeline to not record anything.

```
WARN              interleave interleave.c:319:gst_interleave_set_channel_positions:<interleave> Invalid channel positions, using NONE
```

i'm really new to gstreamer, i was able to create a function to record a single channel, now i'm trying to record stereo and encounter this issue, any information regarding it would be greatly appreciated.

this is the full code:

```
#include <gst/gst.h>

static void on_pad_added(GstElement *element, GstPad *pad, gpointer data);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    setenv("GST_DEBUG", "3", true);

    // return my_sound_dev::gst_main(reinterpret_cast<GstMainFunc>(my_main), argc, argv);
   GMainLoop *loop;
    GstElement *pipeline, *src, *convert, *deinterleave, *interleave, *resample, *encoder, *sink;
    GstPad *pad, *sinkpad;
    GstCaps *caps;

    gst_init(&argc, &argv);

    src = gst_element_factory_make("osxaudiosrc", "source");
    convert = gst_element_factory_make("audioconvert", "convert");
    resample = gst_element_factory_make("audioresample", "resample");
    deinterleave = gst_element_factory_make("deinterleave", "deinterleave"); 
    GstElement *capsfilter = gst_element_factory_make("capsfilter", "filter");
    caps = gst_caps_from_string("audio/x-raw,channels=20,layout=(string)interleaved");
    //caps = gst_caps_from_string("audio/x-raw,channels=2,channel-mask=(bitmask)0x3,layout=(string)interleaved");
    g_object_set (G_OBJECT (capsfilter), "caps", caps, NULL);

    interleave = gst_element_factory_make("interleave", "interleave");
    encoder = gst_element_factory_make("wavenc", "encoder");
    sink = gst_element_factory_make("filesink", "sink");

    g_object_set(src, "device", 97, NULL);
    pipeline = gst_pipeline_new("audio-pipeline");

    gst_bin_add_many(GST_BIN(pipeline), src, deinterleave, interleave, convert, resample, encoder, sink, capsfilter, NULL);

    g_object_set(sink, "location", "/Users/ufk/stereo.wav", NULL);

    if (!gst_element_link_many(src, convert, resample, capsfilter, deinterleave, NULL))
    {
        g_error("Failed to link elements");
        return -1;
    }

    if(!gst_element_link(interleave, encoder)){
        g_error("Failed to link interleave and encoder");
        return -1;
    }


    if(!gst_element_link(encoder, sink)){
        g_error("Failed to link encoder and sink");
        return -1;
    }

    loop = g_main_loop_new(NULL, FALSE);

    g_signal_connect(deinterleave, "pad-added", G_CALLBACK(on_pad_added), interleave);

    if(gst_element_set_state(pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING) == GST_STATE_CHANGE_FAILURE){
        g_error("Could not set pipeline to playing state");
        return -1;
    }

    g_main_loop_run(loop);

    gst_element_set_state(pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);
    gst_object_unref(GST_OBJECT(pipeline));
    g_main_loop_unref(loop);


    return 0;
}

void print_pads(GstElement* element) {
    GValue item = G_VALUE_INIT;
    gboolean done = FALSE;

    GstIterator* it = gst_element_iterate_pads(element);

    while (!done) {
        switch (gst_iterator_next(it, &item)) {
        case GST_ITERATOR_OK: {
                GstPad *pad = GST_PAD(g_value_get_object(&item));
                g_print ("pad name: %s\n", GST_PAD_NAME(pad));
                g_value_reset(&item);
                break;
        }
        case GST_ITERATOR_RESYNC:
            gst_iterator_resync(it);
            break;
        case GST_ITERATOR_ERROR:
        case GST_ITERATOR_DONE:
          done = TRUE;
            break;
        }
    }
    g_value_unset(&item);
    gst_iterator_free(it);
}

void on_pad_added(GstElement *element, GstPad *pad, gpointer data)
{
    char *name;
    GstPad *sinkpad;
    GstElement *queue = gst_element_factory_make("queue", "queue");
    GstElement *sink = (GstElement *)data;

    name = gst_pad_get_name(pad);

    if(g_strcmp0(name, "src_4") == 0){
        sinkpad = gst_element_request_pad_simple(sink, "sink_%u");
    if (!sinkpad)
    {
        g_error("could not create sink for src_4");
    }

        if (gst_pad_is_linked(sinkpad))
        {
            MoLog::fatal() << "sinkpad already linked";
        }
        if (gst_pad_is_linked(pad))
        {
            MoLog::fatal() << "new_pad already linked";
        }
        if (!gst_pad_can_link(pad, sinkpad))
        {
            MoLog::error() << "can't link new_pad to sinkpad";

            GstCaps *new_pad_caps = gst_pad_get_current_caps(pad);
            GstCaps *sinkpad_caps = gst_pad_get_pad_template_caps(sinkpad);
            if (!gst_caps_can_intersect(new_pad_caps, sinkpad_caps)) {
                MoLog::fatal() << "Caps are not compatible";
            } else
            {
                MoLog::info() << "caps can intersect";
            }
            gst_caps_unref(new_pad_caps);
            gst_caps_unref(sinkpad_caps);
        }
        GstPadLinkReturn ret = gst_pad_link(pad, sinkpad);
        if (ret != GST_PAD_LINK_OK){
            print_pads(sink);
            g_error("Error linking pad src_4: %d",ret);
        } else
        {
            g_print("src_4 linked successfully!");
        }

        gst_object_unref(sinkpad);
    }

    else if(g_strcmp0(name, "src_5") == 0){
        sinkpad = gst_element_request_pad_simple(sink, "sink_%u");
        if (!sinkpad)
        {
            g_error("could not create sink for src_5");
        }

        if ((gst_pad_link(pad, sinkpad)) != GST_PAD_LINK_OK){
            g_error("Error linking pad src_5");
        } else
        {
            g_print("successfully linked src_5\n");
        }

        gst_object_unref(sinkpad);
    }

g_free(name);
```

}

i also have a `print_pads(GstElement* element)` for debugging to understand when it creates the pads, but i'm quite lost from here. i used queue in the `gst-launch` but not here.. i'm not sure if i should and if so what's the flow

thanks

Comment: Have you considered to use `gst_parse_launch()` function? If you have a working CLI version this helper is quite useful to get the same functionality into your application.

Comment: @FlorianZwoch - i want to be able to modify the pipe while playing, that is why i prefer not to use gst_parse_launch

Comment: i also want to to catch samples so it's not just that

Comment: I dont think gst_parse_launch prevents you from doing so. Apart from that I may be missing what your actual issue is. One tip is to use "no more pads" signal instead of "pad added". You will then have all pads exposed instead of sequentiall doing it. But that really is preference.

Comment: I am pretty sure you can modify pipeline while playing even when you run it with `gst_parse_launch()`

Comment: check this documentation https://cgit.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gstreamer/tree/docs/design/part-block.txt?h=0.11#n115

and this example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50417045/gstreamer-change-source-element-dynamically

Comment: @Akkshay - thanks, it was helpful. i still want to try to do it without gst_parse_launch to help being dynamic without building the string in case i'll want to record more channels, if i won't i'll go back to that

Comment: in general i made a progress and understood how to record one channel using a queue, hopefully soon i'll get both channels working and i'll paste it here

Answer (score -1, accepted):

so.. it was actually simpler than i thought, it appears that the command like of `gst_parse_launch` is not that different from the flow of the C implementation, i just needed to better understand what's going on.

first i created a capsfilter for 44100 and `S16LE`

```
GstCaps* caps = gst_caps_new_simple("audio/x-raw",
                                         "format", G_TYPE_STRING, "S16LE",
                                         "rate", G_TYPE_INT, bitrate,
                                         NULL);
        GstCaps* fixed = gst_caps_fixate (caps);
        g_object_set (G_OBJECT (capsfilter), "caps", fixed, NULL);
```

later i want to record it to a wav file using libsndfile instead of filesink so i prepared that before hand.

and my inital flow is this:

```
 if (!gst_element_link_many(source, convert, resample, capsfilter, deinterleave, NULL)) {
        gst_object_unref(pipeline);
        MoLog::fatal() << "Elements could not be linked.";
    }
```

it's `osxaudiosrc ! audioconvert !audioresample! capsfilter! deinterleave`

created to `queue` elements and two `audioresample` elements to be used after the queue:

```
queue1 = gst_element_factory_make("queue", "queue1");
    queue2 = gst_element_factory_make("queue", "queue2");
    resample_after_queue1 = gst_element_factory_make("audioresample", "resample-after-queue1");
    resample_after_queue2 = gst_element_factory_make("audioresample", "resample-after-queue2");
```

i request the sink pad for each queue:

```
audio_connected_queue1_sink_pad = gst_element_get_static_pad(queue1, "sink");
        if (!audio_connected_queue1_sink_pad)
        {
            MoLog::fatal() << "interleave sink pad could not be fetched";
            return;
        }

        audio_connected_queue2_sink_pad = gst_element_get_static_pad(queue2, "sink");
        if (!audio_connected_queue2_sink_pad)
        {
            MoLog::fatal() << "interleave sink pad could not be fetched";
            return;
        }
```

and connect each queue to it's resample and to the interleave and the interleave to the sink

```
    if (!gst_element_link_many(queue1, resample_after_queue1, interleave, NULL)) {
        gst_object_unref(pipeline);
        MoLog::fatal() << "Elements could not be linked.";
    }

    if (!gst_element_link_many(queue2, resample_after_queue2, interleave, NULL)) {
        gst_object_unref(pipeline);
        MoLog::fatal() << "Elements could not be linked.";
    }

    if (!gst_element_link(interleave, sink))
    {
        gst_object_unref(pipeline);
        MoLog::fatal() << "could not link interleave and sink.";
    }
```

connnected to the `pad-added` signal of the `deinterleave` element:

```
        g_signal_connect(deinterleave, "pad-added", G_CALLBACK(sound_card_new_pad_handler), this);
```

i created a common function to connect each channel to a queue

```
void SoundCardData::attach_pad(const int channelId, GstPad *nextPad) const
    {
        const std::string srcPadName = "src_" + std::to_string(channelId);

        GstPad *srcPad = gst_element_get_static_pad (deinterleave, srcPadName.c_str());
        if (!srcPad)
        {
            MoLog::fatal() << "could not get deinterlaeve pad " << srcPadName;
        }
        if (gst_pad_is_linked(nextPad))
        {
            MoLog::fatal() << "pad already linked";
        }
        if (gst_pad_is_linked(srcPad))
        {
            MoLog::fatal() << "new_pad already linked";
        }
        if (!gst_pad_can_link(srcPad, nextPad))
        {
            MoLog::error() << "can't link new_pad to sinkpad";

            GstCaps *new_pad_caps = gst_pad_get_current_caps(srcPad);
            GstCaps *sinkpad_caps = gst_pad_get_pad_template_caps(nextPad);
            if (!gst_caps_can_intersect(new_pad_caps, sinkpad_caps)) {
                MoLog::fatal() << "Caps are not compatible";
            } else
            {
                MoLog::info() << "caps can intersect";
            }
            gst_caps_unref(new_pad_caps);
            gst_caps_unref(sinkpad_caps);
        }
        if (gst_pad_link(srcPad, nextPad) != GST_PAD_LINK_OK) {
            g_warning("Failed to link deinterleave pad to encoder");
        }
        MoLog::debug() << "attached pad " << srcPadName << " succesfully!";

    }
```

and in my case i wait for all the pads to be added by counting how much pads where added and compare it the channels in the sound card:

```
 static void sound_card_new_pad_handler(GstElement *src, GstPad *new_pad, gpointer user_data)
    {
        auto data = static_cast<SoundCardData*>(user_data);
        gchar *name = gst_pad_get_name(new_pad);
        // MoLog::debug() << "new_pad_handler executed for " << name;
        data->increasePadChannels();
        g_free(name);
    }
```

and i use this function to like the src pads from interleave to each queue:

```
attach_pad(channelId1, audio_connected_queue1_sink_pad);
attach_pad(channelId2, audio_connected_queue2_sink_pad);
```

and voila! works like charm.